# Whisper Implementation in Bitcoin

Tags: transactions, address, bitcoin-core-development, ethereum

Is there some kind of implementation in `bitcoin` to communicate between nodes, which is similar to the `Whisper Communication in Ethereum` ?

`Whisper`, is a communication protocol for `DApps` to communicate each other without using the `Blockchain` and `Dapps` are something in ethereum which is called as `Decentralized Applications`, which are created using `smart contracts`.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper

Comment: Could you perhaps summarize what Whisper is used for, so that potential answerers don't have to research your question first if they aren't familiar with Whisper?

Comment: @Murch  have added more details about DApps